# Support for Azure Functions Offline

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there a way to run the Azure functions in a standalone server box with no connectivity ?
Our goal is to invoke Azure functions pre-configured in a setup where we would like to invoke the Azure functions while performing specific actions.

Say I have a server box where I copy data into it and as part of the copying of the data we need to perform certain preprocessing and would like to invoke Azure functions for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Azure Functions or Webjobs with Storage Emulator, but it's not a supported scenario.

In the future this scenario will likely be available - it is similar to [Azure Functions on Azure Stack](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/06/microsofts-azure-stack-preview-adds-support-for-azure-functions-and-app-service/), which is in preview.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you that would be preferable to using an emulator that is intended for development purposes would be to leverage Azure IoT Edge, which is a preview product intended for scenarios where connectivity is not always available or bandwidth is a concern.  You can learn more about it at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/campaigns/iot-edge/

Answer (score 0):

As Kyle mentions, Azure IoT Edge allows you to run Azure Functions in an on premises device. [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-simulate-device-linux) walks you through installing the Azure IoT Edge runtime, and [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function) walks you through deploying an Azure Function to your edge device.